# Android ViewModel databinding string.xml

Tags: android, mvvm

#### Question is how does *@{@string/ingredient_item(ingredient.toString())}* work?

```
 <data>
 <variable name="ingredient" type="com.acme.recipes.database.entity.IngredientEntity"/>
</data>
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:text="@{@string/ingredient_item(ingredient.toString())}"
          tools:text="\u2022  1 cup of flour" />
```

String.xml

```
<string name="ingredient_item">\u2022  %1$s</string
```

why is there %1$s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all explain us what is your "IngredientEntity" class?

Second if you are willing to know what **%1$s** is? ->  [Check    here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Which explains  :-

> %[index]$[type]

**index** replicates the index you have passed to it -> which is 1 only [as you have passed only 1 argument to it.]

```
@{@string/ingredient_item(ingredient.toString())}
```

**Type** replicates the type you want to format it here it is -> **s** which indicates string

Lastly  your  digit number of your string indicates bullet .

> • = \u2022, ● = \u25CF, ○ = \u25CB, ▪ = \u25AA, ■ = \u25A0, □ =
>   \u25A1, ► = \u25B